# Swift 3: Web Request with Redirect

Tags: swift, redirect, webrequest

I'm pretty new to Swift and am trying to send a web request to a site that redirects before it provides a response. I know that I need to incorporate willPerformHTTPRedirection, but can't really figure out how to do so and can't find any good examples online.

Is it possible to use willPerformHTTPRedirection with a URLSession.shared.DataTask() method? Or do I need to scrap what I have and start over?

Here is what I have currently:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: newUrl! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {
                let responseData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!,        options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
                print(responseData)
                if let parsedJson = responseData {
                    let userId = parsedJson["id"]
                    print(userId)
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginAccepted", sender: nil)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }; task.resume()

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up switching the way I was sending my requests so I didn't have to deal with redirects, because I was never able to figure this out.